# How do I add dropdown menu to JavaScript template literal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a feature whereby when the user clicks on another user's name a dropdown menu appears with some options. The username is dynamically created using AJAX and template literals. The drop down menu appears to append when I check in dev tools but it doesn't physically appear in the UI. I'm not sure if I am going about it in the right manner. Here is my code:

```
  `
    [...]
       <div class=card-text">
          <p class="venue-text">${venueDescription}</p>
          <h6 class="venue-source card-subtitle" id="${source}-adder" data-idtext="${source}-adder">-${source}</h6>
      </div>
      <div id="o"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      `);
  venueCard.appendTo(myCol);
  myCol.appendTo('#venueCard');

  document.getElementById(source + "-adder").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.matches("h6.venue-source")) {
      let sourceDropdown = document.getElementById('o');
      let dropdown = $(`
          <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="user-options" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></div>
                    <div id="${source}-dropdown" class="venue-card-dropdown dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <a id="share ${source}" data-idtext="share-${source}" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Share</a>
                      <a id="add ${source}" data-idtext="${source}" class="dropdown-item add" href="#">Add to List</a>
                  </div>
            </div>
                  `)
      console.log(`dropdown for ${source}`)
      dropdown.appendTo(sourceDropdown)
    };
  });
```

Comment: You are missing a quote here `class=card-text"`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.